# React Native absolute positioning horizontal centre

Tags: position, react-native, flexbox, absolute

It seems that with `position:absolute` in use an element cannot be centred using `justifyContent` or `alignItems`. There's a workaround to use `marginLeft` but does not display the same for all devices even using dimensions to detect height and width of device.

```js
  bottom: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: height*0.93,
    marginLeft: width*0.18,
  },
  bottomNav: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

Comment: Does your element has static width or dynamic?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Wrap the child you want centered in a View and make the View absolute.

```js
<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <Text>Centered text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Very useful. There's a nice shortcut for those style params hanging off of `StyleSheet` object: `...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject`. see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L29

Comment: Doesn't this make the `View` take up ALL clickable space on the screen? E.g if  I had a component underneath this absolutely positioned `View`, I wouldn't be able to register clicks on it.

Comment: @James111 It looks like you can add `pointerEvents='box-none'` to pass the touches through the view: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12360

Comment: This method recovers the entire image if the text has a background color :/

Comment: @codewise yep, there is a new way to do it, check out my answer

Comment: I used this approach to put a ```LoadIndicator``` on top of a component. I also added  ```backgroundColor: '#000000AA'``` to the style of the wrapping ```View```. That way, you get a nice grayed look while things are loading.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you don't want the absolute container to fill all the space of the parent component for events purposes. The solution with `alignSelf` is best.

Answer (score 138):

If you want to center one element itself you could use **alignSelf**:

```
logoImg: {
    position: 'absolute',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    bottom: '-5%' // only necessary for my example image
}
```

This is an example (Note the logo parent is a view with **position: relative**)

[image]

Comment: alignSelf didn't work for me (it did nothing, in fact). Could you add a little bit more context to the code?

Comment: You need the parent to be display: 'flex' @wilc0

Comment: also works with: `<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <Text>Centered text</Text>
</View>`

Comment: alignSelf worked fine for me, bottom: -5 was not needed.

Comment: the -5 its because as the image posted as an example, I wanted my circle to be "floating between both layouts :) @LalitSharma

Comment: This works perfectly as the absolute element doesn't fill the parent container!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted stops users from accessing elements under the absolute view with touch. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 21):

You can center absolute items by providing the left property with the width of the device divided by two and subtracting out half of the element you'd like to center's width.

For example, your style might look something like this.

```js
bottom: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 25,
    top: height*0.93,
}
```

Comment: this only works if you know the elements width beforehand

Comment: If you don't know the element doesn't have a known width you can use onLayout to get the elements width

`measure(layout) {
     const { width } = layout;
     this.setState({ width: width })
}
...
<View
    onLayout={(event) => { this.measure(event.nativeEvent.layout) }}
...
`

Answer (score 11):

create a full-width `View` with `alignItems: "center"` then insert desired children inside.

```jsx
import React from "react";
import {View} from "react-native";

export default class AbsoluteComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
     <View style={{position: "absolute", left: 0, right: 0, alignItems: "center"}}>
      {this.props.children}
     </View>    
    )
  }
}
```

you can add properties like `bottom: 30` for bottom aligned component.

Comment: This has to be accepted as the correct answer, this works for pretty much every situation.

Answer (score 6):

```js
<View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text>CENTERD TEXT</Text>
</View>
```

And add this

```js
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Short, code-only answers are often frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being flagged as 'low quality', consider adding some explanatory text.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the code

```js
<View
    style={{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        margin: 'auto',
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Haha. This is working for me, However, we need add 
`
style={{
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'row'
    }}
`

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple really. Use percentage for `width` and `left` properties. For example:

```
logo : {
  position: 'absolute',
  top : 50,
  left: '30%',
  zIndex: 1,
  width: '40%',
  height: 150,
}
```

Whatever `width` is, `left` equals `(100% - width)/2`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would use this way to center absolute Views

```js
  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '50%', marginLeft: -22 }}>
           <View style={{ position: 'absolute', width: 44, height: 44}}>
             <Ionicons name="close" color="#4775f2" size={32} />
           </View>
   </View>
```

Notice that In the View which is wrapping the Icon container I'm using left: 50% and the marginLeft is special because you need to put exactly the middle width of the child an turn it negative which in this case is 44 as you can see above, and that's it