# How to place a text over image in react native?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, jsx

How to vertically place a text over image in react native? [I found this doc](https://medium.com/@mheavers/vertically-centering-text-over-images-in-react-native-with-flexbox-935e822751f3). But i can't do like that , I can't add `text` tag as a child component of `Image` tag.I've tried like the below.

```
 <Card>
    <CardSection>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image source={require('../Images/4.jpg')} style={styles.imageStyl}  />
    <Text style={styles.userStyle}>       
            {this.props.cat.name}
             </Text>
             </View>
            </CardSection>
            </Card>
const styles= StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
         flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    imageStyl: {
    flexGrow:1,
    width:"100%",
    height:200,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
    userStyle:{
        fontSize:18,
        color:'black',
        fontWeight:'bold',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
});
```

How to place the text to the center of image?Getting something like this [image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have to use in the "css" 
`position:'absolute'`
And then place your text using the css properties (like top, bottom, right, left)

---

[React Native absolute positioning horizontal centre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317568/react-native-absolute-positioning-horizontal-centre)

Wrap the child you want centered in a View and make the View absolute.

`<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <Text>Centered text</Text>
</View>`

Answer (score 47):

use this:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('background image path')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
   <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
     <Text>Centered text</Text>
   </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: This is more convenient way to achieve that.

Comment: its worked fine here! you save my day!

Answer (score 18):

You can import `ImageBackground` instead of `Image` from `react-native` and pass the text as children to the `ImageBackground`. This does the magic. Please see the code below:

```
<View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
     <ImageBackground style={styles.theImage} source={{uri : item.imageUrl}}>
          <Text>Hey</Text>
     </ImageBackground>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageWrapper: {
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        overflow : "hidden"
    },
    theImage: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        resizeMode: "cover",
    }
})
```

We can use positioning too as stated by many, but I prefer using `ImageBackground`.

Answer (score 4):

I have my own component to do so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const BackgroundImage = (props) => {

  const { container, image } = styles;


  return (

    <View style={container}>
      <Image
      style={[image, 
        { resizeMode: props.resizeMode,    
        opacity: props.opacity}
      ]}  
      source={props.source}***strong text***
      />
    </View>

  )
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,   
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  image: {  
    flex: 1,  
  }
};

export {BackgroundImage};
```

that component will fill your container with any image you wish ;)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

class List extends Component {
   render() {
    let source = {uri: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'};
    return (
           <View style = {{backgroundColor: 'black'}>
              <BackgroundImage
               resizeMode="cover"
               opacity={0.6}
               source={source}
               />
               <Text>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
     )
   }
   export default List;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its so similar like normal HTML and CSS place a text over image. You have to place a text over image by making text's absolute.

- modified those code as it is :

  ```
  userStyle:{
      position : absolute;
      bottom : 0,
      top : 50,
      left : 0,
      right : 0,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent:'center',
  }
  ```

I hope those code will fix your problem.

Comment: the question is about react native