# How to show a text over an image when the computer mouse is above it? (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, image

how do I make it so that when my mouse is above an image, a text appeared on the image(while keeping the image)?
There is an answer for a text above the image without the "when my mouse is above an image" part here :
[How to place a text over image in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250047/how-to-place-a-text-over-image-in-react-native)
But it's not what I want.
Here is my code:

```
         <View
            style={{
              flex: 7.5,
              //alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={screen2}
              style={{
                width: "80%",
                height: "80%",
                marginBottom: 150,
                marginTop: 120,
                marginLeft: "15%",
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: The screen2 is an image that i have in local. You can replace it with a : {
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }

Comment: What mouse? Is this question about react-native?

Comment: Yes, when the arrow go above your image in this website, I want this immage to have a text appered (ex: image of a banana, the arrow is above it, it became an image of a banana with the text banana in the middle)